# Get Unique Email Identifier from GMail in Java

Tags: java, gmail, imap

My Java Application needs to know the unique email identifier that is present at the end of every GMail URL. I can extract the identifier in javascript but I don't know how to handle that problem in Java.
My Java code is the following:

```
drafts=store.getFolder("inbox");
drafts.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] msgDrafts = drafts.getMessages();
System.out.println("Total Drafts Msg Count IS : -----------   " + msgDrafts.length);
int msgNum= msgDrafts.length-number+1;
FetchProfile fpDrafts = new FetchProfile();
drafts.fetch(msgDrafts, fpDrafts);
// for (Message m : ms) {

for (int j = msgDrafts.length-1; j >= 0; j--) {                 
    Message im = msgDrafts[j];
```

**I wanna retrieve that identifier from im**

Comment: Can you use the Class MimeMessage instead of Message? Then you could use the method getMessageID(). Not sure if that is the same ID though.

Comment: That's not the same ID. The message he wants is called X-GM-MSGID in gmail/imap, and is expressed as a 64-bit integer in the IMAP interface. There's a javamail gmail/imap extension to get at it. getMessageId returns a string such as <feioruweioruweiorweu@example.com>, which is set by the sender, should always be present, actually is present on about 99.92% of non-spam mail messages (as I counted it last time I counted), and which is very occasionally not unique (no numbers though).